# How to unlock all moon missions Destiny PS3?

Tags: destiny

[image: my moon map]

I saw online and on the map that there are more moon missions that I can’t go to. I don’t know if I have to find the mission in patrol or something or if it has something to do with the purple crown icon. The icon is on an earth mission but it’s a Taken King mission and I don’t have any dlc. And I’m pretty sure that I can’t go to Venus or mars because of the other moon missions. So how do I progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've kind of answered your own question - you cannot play the Taken King missions without the Taken King DLC. As for the regular missions, make sure you've done everything you can up to that point. Maybe you have to go to the Tower before you go to do that mission, so try that. Also check if there was any more Earth missions you may have missed, as you might be expected to complete the Earth missions before going further on the Moon. The only other thing I can think of is do all the Strikes that you have available as well. Hope this helps!